# SQL Server - How to lock a table until a stored procedure finishes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, locking

I want to do this:

```
create procedure A as
  lock table a
  -- do some stuff unrelated to a to prepare to update a
  -- update a
  unlock table a
  return table b
```

Is something like that possible?

Ultimately I want my SQL server reporting services report to call procedure A, and then only show table a after the procedure has finished.  (I'm not able to change procedure A to return table a).

Comment: Have you considered using SET TRANSACTION / COMMIT . I'm not too sure what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: Xin's answer was much more concise and less resource intensive. I had to use TABLOCKX though.

Answer (score 64):

Needed this answer myself and from the [link provided by David Moye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3662820/641833), decided on this and thought it might be of use to others with the same question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  -- lock table "a" till end of transaction
  SELECT ...
  FROM a
  WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
  WHERE ...

  -- do some other stuff (including inserting/updating table "a")



  -- release lock
  COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: Can't we use sp_getapplock for this

Comment: From the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), it seems sp_getapplock will also do the job with sp_releaseapplock being used for releasing the lock.  Also has the advantage of not needing to be inside a transaction by the looks of it.

Comment: TABLOCK will prevent updates by other sessions, TABLOCKX would prevent both updates and reads.

Comment: Additionaly you can insert the lock-select into a table variable in order to hide it from the output, if needed: `DECLARE  @HideSelectFromOutput TABLE ( DoNotOutput INT); INSERT INTO @HideSelectFromOutput SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM a WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK);`

Comment: Isnt the lock only in use when running one select statement in this solution?

Comment: @Anders - The lock remains in force until the COMMIT.  You can put many statements before this.

Answer (score 29):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

select top 1 *
from table1
with (tablock, holdlock)

-- You do lots of things here

COMMIT
```

This will hold the 'table lock' until the end of your current "transaction".

Answer (score 19):

Use the TABLOCKX lock hint for your transaction. [See this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15) for more information on locking.

Comment: You could, alternatively, use UPDLOCK if it's okay for others to read the table while you're using it.

Comment: Where does the transaction come in?  Should I wrap my whole SP in a transaction?

Comment: For many SPs, it makes sense to begin a transaction at the beginning and commit it at the end. There are, of course, exceptions to this rule, but in general I find it a good practice.