# Locking tables in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, locking

I have an SQL Database with a table that I would like to lock. I'm using Entity Framework. Basically, there are a number of processes that each want to write to the database concurrently. Each of them wants to update a row in some table. However, I want only one of them to be able to do this at the same time.

Is there a way of locking an entire table, such as to prevent anyone from putting new rows or updating rows?

Thanks,
Christian

Comment: That's the default behaviour. You shouldn't have to do anything, aside from using transactions, if you are changing several tables in one operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me *why* you would want this, but if you really want to lock the whole table you could:

- Turn off row and page locking so that everything escalates to a table lock

Example adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779358/how-to-i-force-lock-escalation-to-flush-out-deadlock-issues-during-testing):

```
ALTER INDEX [MyIndexName] ON [dbo].[MyTableName] SET ( ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF)
```

*Note: this assumes your application solely "owns" these tables -- wouldn't want to apply this and break some other app*

- Set your queries to use Serializable isolation level

Example adapted from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3740.entity-framework-faq-connections-and-transactions.aspx#How_do_I_set_IsolationLevel_Lock_Hints_on_single_queries_Is_it_possible_to_set_NOLOCK_on_a_query):

```
TransactionOptions topt = new TransactionOptions();   
topt.IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.Serializable;
using (var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, topt)) {
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the short description, it is doubtful that a table lock is really what is needed to solve this issue.  Some common solutions that are much more scalable include:

> 1) Create a serializable transaction that reads or updates the record of interest as the first statement.  All updates should try to follow this pattern.
>
> 2) Create a read_committed transaction like (1) but include a re-read/retry ability on an concurrency exception.

It is rare that one should ever need to lock a table.  One case it may be necessary when there is some calculation involved for a manually determined identity field value and a chance of collision with another session.

For *just that call*, a transaction can be created and the table locked at the beginning. The lock can be "X" (exclusive) to prevent reads and writes or non-exclusive to just prevent writes.  This answer uses an SP:

[SO #3662766](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662766/sql-server-how-to-lock-a-table-until-a-stored-procedure-finishes/3662820#3662820)

As an alternative, an application lock could also be used.

[sp_getapplock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx)