# Can I change default isolation level in entity framework/sql server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, currency, isolation-level

Like in the question is any method to change default isolation level in ef / on ms sql server? I have on mind change for "all time" not only for a current transaction

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework and transaction isolation level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795184/entity-framework-and-transaction-isolation-level)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to make such changes in the database, sure.

```
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL <whatever>
```

More info on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)