# T-SQL ways to avoid potentialy updating the same row based on subquery results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, locking

I have a SQL Server table with records (raw emails) that needs to be processed (build the email and send it) in a given order by an external process (mailer).  Its not very resource intensive but can take a while with all the parsing and SMTP overhead etc.

To speed things up I can easily run multiple instance of the mailer process over multiple servers but worry that if two were to start at almost the same time they might still overlap a bit and send the same records.

Simplified for the question my table look something like this with each record having the data for the email.

```
queueItem
======================
  queueItemID PK
  ...data...
  processed bit
  priority int
  queuedStart datetime
  rowLockName varchar
  rowLockDate datetime
```

**Batch 1 (*Server 1*)**

- starts at 12:00PM
- lock/reserve the first 5000 rows (1-5000)
- select the newly reserved rows
- begin work

**Batch 2 (*Server 2*)**

- starts at 12:15PM
- lock/reserve the next 5000 rows (5001-10000)
- select the newly reserved rows
- begin work

To lock the rows I have been using the following:

```
declare @lockName varchar(36)
set @lockName = newid()
declare @batchsize int
set @batchsize = 5000

update queueItem
  set rowLockName = @lockName,
  rowLockDate = getdate()
where queueitemID in (
  select top(@batchsize) queueitemID 
  from queueItem
  where processed = 0
  and rowLockName is null
  and queuedStart <= getdate()
  order by priority, queueitemID 
)
```

If I'm not mistaken the query would start executing the *SELECT* subquery first and then lock the rows in preparation of the *update*, this is fast but not instantaneous.

My concern is that if I start two batches at near the same time (faster than the subquery runs) *Batch 1's UPDATE* might not be completed and *Batch 2's SELECT* would see the records as still available and attempt/succeed in overwriting Batch 1 (sort of race condition?)

I have ran some test but so far haven't had the issue with them overlapping, is it a valid concern that will come to haunt me at the worst of time?

Perhaps there are better way to write this query worth looking into as I am by no mean a T-SQL guru.

Comment: Your process could begin by exclusively locking the table; and until you have the lock do nothing; once lock is acquired, update with name, release lock so next process can lock and update. (this means while this process is running updates/inserts to the data would be affected/queued; and if too long may time out)

Comment: You may want to move this to the code review site

Comment: @xQbert looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/23759307/70424 it looks like that might be what I am looking for indeed. I wasn't aware of that query hint.

Comment: @jfrobishow cant we update each 5000 rows in loop using WHILE or GOTO with temporary table in a single statement and in same instance ? if you just want to speed up the update query.

Comment: @Suraz Perhaps I might be missing something from your idea, but wouldn't it risk the same chance of two row being selected for update if multiple sessions run the same update?