# MySQL "lock" a table entry

Tags: php, mysql, sql, thread-safety, locking

Is there a way to lock table entries in SQL/MySQL? I'm looking for something like this (in php, but it should not matter):

Pseudo-Code:

```
waitForTableEntryWithKey("somekey");
lockTableEntryWithKey("somekey");

doSomethingWithSQL();

unlockTableEntryWithKey("somekey");
```

`doSomethingWithSQL()` must not be executed more than one time at a time for a certain table entry. Is there a way to do this in SQL, except for creating a `locked bool` in the table and querying it while waiting (it just seems like an improper solution)?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662766/sql-server-how-to-lock-a-table-until-a-stored-procedure-finishes

Comment: I don't want to lock the whole table. Just one row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are speaking about row lock ant it can be achieved with MySQL InnoDB.
Please take a look into [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-reads.html).
How it should be described in the PHP script is very depends on the tools which you are using for communication with DB.