# How to place range/table lock at 2 tables at MS SQL server via pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am now processing 2 tables at the same time by pyodbc.
Before finishing processing, I would like to place locks on the 2 tables so that nobody can change the 2 tables before I finish.
How can I do that?

I tried the below, but failed with an error.

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("conn_str")
conn.execute("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;")
conn.execute("begin transaction trans;")
cur1 = conn.execute("select * from tbl1;")
cur2 = conn.execute("select * from tbl2;")
... some processing at cur1 and cur2 at python ...
conn.execute("commit transaction trans;")
```

However, the following error comes up when execution "cur2 = conn.execute("select * from tbl2;")"

```
[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Connection is busy with results for another hstmt (0) (SQLExecDirectW)
```

Is there anything wrong with my code? Highly appreciated for any help.

Comment: Have you seen pyodbc's [wiki entry](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Database-Transaction-Management#specifying-a-transaction-isolation-level) that talks about transaction isolation levels?

Comment: You need to run the queries on different connections since only one can be active on a connection at a time (unless you were to use MARS).

Comment: @GordThompson: I tried exactly the same at the link, but it failed with the following error [pyodbc.Error: ('HY011', u'[HY011] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Operation invalid at this time (0) (SQLSetConnectAttr)')]. It seems that the isolation level cannot be changed after the connection is open [pyodbc.connect()]. However, it seems that pyodbc does not allow me to create an pyodbc.Connection directly without a connection str specified.

Comment: @DanGuzman I tried again. FInally, I can do it at the same connection. But I need to consume cur1 (for example, for row in cur1: do sth) before using cur2. Although I can solve the error, it is against my original thoughts that locking the 2 tables together as soon as possible.

Comment: re: "Operation invalid at this time" - Sorry about that. The instructions on the wiki page were incorrect. They have been fixed.

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662766/sql-server-how-to-lock-a-table-until-a-stored-procedure-finishes . With `TABLOCK` hint you may be able to do something like this: `SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableA WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) UNION ALL SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM TableB WITH (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK)` to lock both tables at once. Then you can read them again to get data.

Comment: @GordThompson: Thanks for your update. It is ok now. It seems that I cannot change the isolation level after transaction starts instead of connection started. So, you use "autocommit = False" initially to suppress the the transaction. However, as I know, in "SERIALIZABLE" mode, table is locked by range lock when it is selected. So, if I want to lock 2 tables/ranges at the same time. It seems that that I can only do a query, something like "select 1 from tbl1 where col1 = 1 union all select 1 from tbl2 where col1 = 1", which is quite dummy and dirty I think. Is there any proper way to do so?

Comment: @Alex: Thanks. It seems that (TABLOCK, HOLDLOCK) is for the whole table. Sometimes, in my case, range lock is need while sometimes, table lock is needed. Also, it needs a dummy SQL statement in order to lock. Is it a proper way to do so or any other more elegant ways? After a few researches, it seems that it is the only way to do so. Just want to find out better way if any.

Comment: As @DanGuzman hinted in an earlier comment, you could try appending `;MARS_Connection=yes` to your connection string.

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks for your reminder. Just tried but it seems that my server does not support MARS, so the parameter is a kind of no function here.It seems that I either do a dummy select in order to lock 2 tables at the same time or just select them separately in a short time. By the way, I would to mark your reply as answer, but I cannot do it on a comment. Maybe you can change to post an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, SQL Server ODBC was limited to one active `hstmt` (the ODBC equivalent of a `pyodbc.cursor`) per connection. Later on, Microsoft added the MARS (Multiple Active Result Sets) feature to SQL Server ODBC, but that feature is "off" by default.

So this code

```python
import pyodbc
import sys

print(f"Python version {sys.version}")  # Python version 3.6.4 ...
print(f"pyodbc version {pyodbc.version}")  # pyodbc version 4.0.24
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    r'SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDb;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str, autocommit=True)

cnxn.set_attr(pyodbc.SQL_ATTR_TXN_ISOLATION, pyodbc.SQL_TXN_SERIALIZABLE)
cnxn.autocommit = False  # enable transactions

cur1 = cnxn.execute("SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS x")
cur2 = cnxn.execute("SELECT 'foo' AS y UNION ALL SELECT 'bar' AS y")

print(cur1.fetchone())
print(cur2.fetchone())
print(cur1.fetchone())
print(cur2.fetchone())
```

fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Gord/PycharmProjects/py3pyodbc_demo/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    cur2 = cnxn.execute("SELECT 'foo' AS y UNION ALL SELECT 'bar' AS y")
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

However, if we add `MARS_Connection=yes` to the connection string

```python
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    r'SERVER=.\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'DATABASE=myDb;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    r'MARS_Connection=yes;'
)
```

then the code works.

Unfortunately in your case you are using the ancient `DRIVER=SQL Server` which is too old to support `MARS_Connection=yes` so your options are

- use a newer version of the SQL Server ODBC driver, or
- open two separate connections, one for each cursor.

Comment: Thanks so much. ^_^